# number of integrable functions is greater than number of differentiable functions

Tags: calculus

It is said that number of integrable functions is greater than number of differentiable functions.Why so?But in reality isn't it quite the opposite?

Comment: Riemann integrable? What do you mean by number? Do you agree that all continuous functions are Riemann integrable but not all of them are differentiable?

Comment: http://www.hyper-ad.com/tutoring/math/calculus/Antiderivatives%20and%20the%20Riemann%20Integral.html   I asked this question due to the para on "Integrable Functions"

Answer (score 3):

The class of integrable functions, $I$, includes all the continuous functions, $C$. The class of differentiable functions, $D$, is strictly contained in the class of continuous functions (i.e. a function has to be continuous to be differentiable, but examples like $|x|$ show that there are non-differentiable continuous functions, and Weierstrass et al. showed that there are nowhere-differentiable continuous functions). Hence you have the strict inclusions
$$ I \supset C \supset D, $$
so there are more functions in $I$ than $D$.

Answer (score 2):

You are mis-interpreting the statement.  You appear to take "integrable" and "differentiable" to mean "I can find the indefinite integral (or the derivative) in closed form in terms of elementary functions" but that is not what those terms mean to a mathematician doing analysis.

A differentiable function is a function for which the limit defining the derivative exists at all points. An integrable function is a function that has an integral in the sense of Riemann integration (dividing up the interval and summing values) or perhaps in the sense of Lebesgue integrals — regardless of whether we can express the value of that integral in simple or closed form.

The question then arises: Does there exist a map taking integrable functions to differentiable functions such that every differentiable function is the image of some integrable function under that map?  And conversely, can there be a surjective map from the set of differentiable functions to the set of integrable functions.

Perhaps surprisingly, one can prove that there are maps from the integrables to the differentiables that cover all the differentiables, but not the other way around.  This is what is meant when we say there are more integrable than differentiable functions.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite obviously both infintely many integrable and infinitely many differentiable functions. So for the statement to make any kind of sense you have to talk about the cardinality of the sets.

If by "greater than" you mean "have at least the same cardinality" you just need to find a function that maps every differentiable function to an integrable function to prove the statement. Such a map is really easy to find.